Check if hyperlink available and concatenate hyperlinked values
Dim Temp As String
If (Range(Cells(2, 1).Address).Hyperlinks.Count > 0) Then
            Temp = Range(Cells(2, 1).Address).Hyperlinks(1).Address
            New_Sheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = Join(Range(Range(Temp).Offset(0, 1).Address, Range(Temp).Offset(Range(Temp).End(xlDown), 0).Address), ", ")
End If

This code is giving Runtime error 1004 in the Value assignment line. Unable to identify the error here. Please help.
I have a list of possible values in the cell hyperlinked to the main sheet. These values are listed in a column below the header. I want to concatenate all these values in a single cell using comma separator.
I tried using address, follow, parent properties but nothing gave me the desired result.

maybe Range(Temp).End(xlDown).Row

You don't need to keep doing range(range.address) just  cells(2,1)  will do  like you have in line 4.

What do you expect from Join in the context you show? Firstly, is Temp a cell address? A cell address in the same active sheet? Please, copy its value and show it to us. Secondly, supposing that the first assumption is correct, do you want returning a concatenation between the cells in the next column after Temp, up to the first empty row looking down?

In fact, did you check what does Range(Cells(2, 1).Address).Hyperlinks(1).Address return? If that cell should be in the same sheet, I think it should be returned using .Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress. This will not solve the problem you have with your code but you will have a good start. If you clarify the issue, I can show to you where the problems are...
